# Rendering Barnsley Fern fractal without the probabilities

Tags: java, algorithm, fractals

I was making a program that renders a mutation of the Barnsley Fern fractal. My program works flawlessly and generates exactly the output which I want it to generate. I went further into reading about the Iterated Function Systems and read that these fractals can be renders without the use of probabilities and performing all the four Affine Transformations in each iteration. I know that this will increase the computation time but I want to know how can we remove the probabilities out of picture?

For example the probability for the four functions that draw my fern are 2%, 84%, 7% and 7% respectively.

Here is the question again in bold for those who say, "I cannot find the question in the post." : **How do we use all the four functions in every iteration instead of choosing one of the four, based on probability?**

Here is the relevant code:

**AffineTransformation.java**

```
public class AffineTransformation
{
    private double[][] transformation=new double[2][2];
    private double[][] translation=new double[2][1];
    public AffineTransformation(double a,double b,double c,double d,double e,double f)
    {
        transformation[0][0] = a;
        transformation[0][1] = b;
        transformation[1][0] = c;
        transformation[1][1] = d;
        translation[0][0] = e;
        translation[1][0] = f;
    }
    public Point transform(Point point)
    {
        double x = point.getX();
        double y = point.getY();
        double u = 0.0;
        double v = 0.0;
        u = transformation[0][0]*x + transformation[0][1]*y;
        v = transformation[1][0]*x + transformation[1][1]*y;
        u = u + translation[0][0];
        v = v + translation[1][0];
        return new Point(u,v);
    }
}
```

**The rendering loop**

```
AffineTransformation f1 = new AffineTransformation(0,0,0,0.25,0,-0.4);
AffineTransformation f2 = new AffineTransformation(0.95,0.005,-0.005,0.93,-0.002,0.5);
AffineTransformation f3 = new AffineTransformation(0.035,-0.2,0.16,0.04,-0.09,0.02);
AffineTransformation f4 = new AffineTransformation(-0.04,0.2,0.16,0.04,0.083,0.12);
Point point = new Point(0.5,0.0);
int N=Width*Height;
for(int i=0;i< N*25;i++)
{
    Point newpoint = new Point();
    double probability = Math.random();
    if(probability < 0.02)
    {
        newpoint = f1.transform(point);
        color=new Color(0x002147);
    }
    else if(probability < 0.86)
    {
        newpoint = f2.transform(point);
        color=new Color(0x120A8F);
    }
    else if(probability < 0.93)
    {
        newpoint = f3.transform(point);
        color=new Color(0x002147);
    }
    else
    {
        newpoint = f4.transform(point);
        color=new Color(0x002147);
    }
    point = newpoint;
    int X=((int)(point.getX()*W/3)+W/2)/2 + W/4-1;
    int Y=(int)(point.getY()*H/8) + H/9 -1;
    image.setRGB(X,Y, color.getRGB());
}
```

**EDIT**
The main thing I wanted to achieve by discarding probs. was test my own transformation functions for which obviously I would not know the probability except by trial and error. Any help there?

To elaborate, suppose I have four other functions and I don't know what probability to use, is there a method to know the probability except by trial and error.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understand you correctly, but I thing you want:

    `point = f4.transform(f3.transform(f2.transform(f1.transform(point)))); //Ad infinitum`

But this leaves you with the problem of choosing a color

Comment: @Dawnkeeper You exactly understood me. But I already tried the thing you suggested. This thing renders just a single pixel on the image. The point keeps coming the same in every iteration. :(

Comment: Yes, just tested it myself and this is not the solution ... hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a way to determine the probabilities that should be used for a perfect image using the Affine Transformation functions. The method which requires the probabilities for rendering is called the **Random Iteration Algorithm**.

The method I am about to describe here has been taken from **Michael F. Barnsley**'s book, **Fractals Everywhere** (Chapter 3, under the heading: TWO ALGORITHMS FOR COMPUTING FRACTALS FROM ITERATED FUNCTION SYSTEMS).

Each Affine transformation function can be represented as:

[image: Affine Transformation]

Now if we use **N** functions for drawing a fractal, the probability **P<sub>i</sub>** to be used for each function is given by:

[image: Probability function]

where **|det. A<sub>i</sub>|** is the absolute value of determinent of the matrix **A<sub>i</sub>** which is given by: **|a.d - b.c|**

If, for some **i**, we get **P<sub>i</sub>=0** the we assign **P<sub>i</sub>** a small positive value like 0.001.

While finally using the probabilities for rendering it should be noted that **∑ P<sub>i</sub>**=1

Example:

Suppose we have four Affine Transformation functions with matrix values **(a,b,c,d)** as follows:

> A<sub>1</sub> = **(0, 0, 0, 0.25)**
>   A<sub>2</sub> = **(0.95, 0.005, -0.005, 0.93)**
>   A<sub>3</sub> = **(0.035, -0.2, 0.16, 0.04)**
>   A<sub>4</sub> = **(-0.04, 0.2, 0.16, 0.04)**

Now:

> |det. A<sub>1</sub>| =  |(0*0.25)-(0*0)| = **0**
>   |det. A<sub>2</sub>| =  |(0.95*0.93)-(0.005*-0.005)| = **0.883525**
>   |det. A<sub>3</sub>| =  |(0.035*0.04)-(-0.2*0.16)| = **0.0334**
>   |det. A<sub>4</sub>| =  |(-0.04*0.04)-(0.2*0.16)| = **0.0336**

And summation of all **A<sub>i</sub>s** = **(0 + 0.883525 + 0.0334 + 0.0336) = 0.950525**

And then the probabilities are:

> P<sub>1</sub>  = 0 ≈ **0.01**
>   P<sub>2</sub>  = 0.883525/0.950525 = 0.929512637 ≈ **0.93**
>   P<sub>3</sub>  = 0.0334/0.950525 = 0.0351384761 ≈ **0.03**
>   P<sub>4</sub>  = 0.0336/0.950525 = 0.0353488861 ≈ **0.03**

So, the final probabilities are: **1%, 93%, 3%, 3%** which sum up to 100% which can used as a check.

By the way, these four functions generate a mutation of Barnsley Fern.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the transforms has a specific function (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern#Computer_generation))
So chaining them together like we already tried doesn't work.

What would work is something like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i< N*25;i++)
    {
        Point newpoint1 = f1.new Point(0,0);
        Point newpoint2 = f1.new Point(0,0);
        Point newpoint3 = f1.new Point(0,0);
        Point newpoint4 = f1.new Point(0,0);
        double probability = Math.random();

        newpoint1 = f1.transform(point);

        newpoint2 = f2.transform(point);

        newpoint3 = f3.transform(point);

        newpoint4 = f4.transform(point);


        drawToImage(image, newpoint1, Width, Height, Color.red);
        drawToImage(image, newpoint2, Width, Height, Color.green);
        drawToImage(image, newpoint3, Width, Height, Color.red);
        drawToImage(image, newpoint4, Width, Height, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        if(probability < 0.02)
        {
             point = newpoint1;
        }
        else if(probability < 0.86)
        {
             point = newpoint2;
        }
        else if(probability < 0.93)
        {
             point = newpoint3;
        }
        else
        {
             point = newpoint4;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that you still have to choose a point for the next step at random or it wont work. You just increase the calculations per cycle.

Do you have a link to the source of the 'can be run without probabilities' claim and even better a statement regarding the improvements by doing so?

**Edit after reading up a bit**

The algorithm you are using now is generating the fractal is point by point. See [Chaos game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game)

The Wikipedia descriptions of [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) also has an example using the whole image and applying the transformations to get a new image and then start over with the new image again. This would not require the randomness.

I could not test this, so no idea if it really works.

Comment: I read it here: http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/teaching/wpo/grafsys/ex4/les4.html

Comment: The main thing I wanted to achieve by discarding probs. was test my own transformation functions for which obviously I would not know the probability except by trial and error. Any help there? To elaborate, suppose I have four other functions and I don't know what probability to use, is there a method to know the probability except by trial and error.

Comment: Sorry, but for this you will need someone who REEEEEALLY likes maths ^_^

Comment: Well guess what? I am the one who really likes maths. Check my answer above. ^_^